# Web Deploy not working. Timeout on client. Schannel 1203 on server

Tags: powershell, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, webdeploy

I'm trying to deploy an application via web deploy to a windows 2012 r2 server.

First tried installing iis, web deploy using the msi. After getting an unreachable error I saw somewhere that I needed wmsvc to be installed and installed it via powershell command **Install-WindowsFeature Web-Mgmt-Service**.

I stopped getting the unreachable error and started getting this error ->

```
Error: Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'http://xx.x.xx.xx:8172/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE'.

Error: The operation has timed out
```

On the server's event viewer under system I get the following error ->

```
A fatal alert was generated and sent to the remote endpoint. This may result in termination of the connection. The TLS protocol defined fatal error code is 10. The Windows SChannel error state is 1203.
```

Any idea of what could be going on? Did I miss something on the installation?

After this I also tried installing everything but *without* iis and I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

So, this is really not a PoSH issue. 
Maybe you should consider movin gthis question to another forum.

Anyway, you have either real server config issues (this can sometimes mean wipe and rebuild - very ugly option - but if it's a virtual machine and you have a snapshot, just roll back), or an app causing this.

Typically for Schannel type of error, it has to do with application or service in machine not able to complete any SSL connection sort of connection.

The error state parameter of 1203 means client error connecting to server, ie invalid ClientHello from the client

See if you can collect more data by...

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/260729/how-to-enable-schannel-event-logging-in-iis

Answer (score 1):

I realized this is an old question, but in case somebody ran into the same issue, here are my solution.

1. I had to follow this guidelines : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-server-environments-for-web-deployment/configuring-a-web-server-for-web-deploy-publishing-web-deploy-handler
2. Copy the resulting publishsetting file. In the Publish/Profile page import it.
3. In the Publish/Connection page, change the server to the server address with the 8172 port. Add the password. Change the Destination URL to the site to go to after the publish is completed.

Then after Validate connection was completed, go ahead and publish it!